# What does SHR on ASM mean

Tags: assembly, x86

I am confused as what SHR means,

```
SHR CL, 1
```

Initially CL was `0x2A` after being SHR it became `0x15`.

> SHR 42, 1 = 21

Comment: What does assembler have to do with Javascript?

Comment: I'm just trying to convert the code to javascript from assembly.

Comment: Why don't you look it up in the documentation for whichever instruction set you're using?

Comment: I'm using OllyDBG. Why the down vote?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+shr+in+assembly - First link. "shr right shifts (unsigned divides) a byte, word, or long value for a count specified by an immediate value and stores the quotient in that byte, word, or long respectively.". You should really put more effort into your questions.

Comment: Yeah, too late. I just realized with the answer of Bushmills.

Comment: shr (shift "bits" right) divides by 2 each shift, shl (shift "bits" left) multiples by 2 each shift, so if you shifted the number `0x2A` or `0010-1010` once to the right you get `0x15` or `0001-0101`

Comment: -1 because of a lack of research. It can be found out in a few seconds with a simple google request. And it isn't added the correct tag add the beginning since there's no "asm" in general.

Comment: The answer can be found with a trivial Google search with keywords: shr assembly . So the question shows no effort and is of low quality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply put, Shift Right. The second operand defines the amount of bits to be shifted right. So :

CL = 42(in hex) = 0100 0010 (binary)

Shift right one time, all the bits go right. The lowest significant bit(rightmost) goes to the carry flag and a zero is appended on the highest significant bit (leftmost). The value thus becomes :

0010 0001 (21 in hex) -> and the rightmost 0 goes to the carry flag.

Comment: I don't know why people always ask about shifting when almost all languages have shift operator/instruction and they should encounter it when learning the language

Answer (score 3):

Look at both values in binary representation, rather than as hex numbers, that makes it much more obvious what the instruction does.
Extra points for noticing the distinct pattern when dividing first number by second number.

Comment: seems like a division.

Comment: can be used as such, right, But that's merely a side effect, a result of the fact that the computer works on binary numbers, About as much of a side effect as stripping a trailing digit from a decimal number is an (integer) division by ten.